# Consolidate texture files, removing unused portions

Tags: python, texturing

I have a 3D model of a sculpture created with WebODM. It contains a lot of background that is not wanted, which I remove with Blender. However, I am left with many (in my current case, 234) texture files which still contain data for all of the removed portions of the model. I would like to remove the (now) unused portions of the texture files and consolidate these to fewer/smaller files.

Two goals:

1. simplify/reduce the amount of data for faster load times;
2. get the total size small enough so that I can upload it to Sketchfab.

As I need to do this frequently, I think it would be preferable to do this with scripts (but I'm open to other options), rather than manually each time. I do not have the knowledge of Blender to tackle this myself. Can anyone help or point me to additional information?

Thank you.

Comment: Hello, could you add a screenshot of how your file is structured ? Have you tried baking your multi-textures into one ?